# How do I order Vertices in Blender?

Tags: node-editor, vertices, vertex-groups

I am writing a low polygon engine for old hardware, and in order to minimise the workload on the engine i need to group the vertices for each 'body-part'. Thus head may be 1-60, torso 60-120, right upper arm 120-150 etc

Unfortunately i am more used to building FE models (beginner with blender, experienced with nastran) than 3D models for games, and when i import the stl file, of course all the node/vertex IDs are lost.

Is there any way to either retain existing IDs or to quickly group and reorder IDs once imported into blender?

Comment: OK i think i have a work around... I will write a piece of code to convert bdf file to obj, that is convert GRIDs to v and CTRIA/CQUAD to f nodeID// and let blender fill in the texture co-ords and normals should have thought of it quicker. Would be nice though still to figure out how to group in blender. I maybe need to read more.

Answer (score 0):

[Vertex Groups](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/properties/vertex_groups/assigning_vertex_group.html) are for grouping vertices. You could also add custom attributes to geometry. Have a look at the Data tab in the Properties Editor:

[image]

And then you do with that whatever you want to do:

```
import bpy

o = bpy.context.object
d = o.data

for vert in d.vertices:
    output = "Vert " + str(vert.index) + " groups: "
    group_names =[o.vertex_groups[item[0]].name for item in vert.groups.items()]
    print(output + ", ".join(group_names))
```

[image]

I just wanted to admire a printout of my vertex group names for every single vertex here, but you may use that to export your mesh in whatever format your engine would use.